# No route to host error while Building Docker Image using Dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

I am trying to run following command in my `dockerfile` for downloading pandas package

```
RUN curl -x proxy.temp.com:8080 -U myid_9076:pwd123* -L -O https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b4/31/bbd2c915aad67c7cb572b7c6ca8f645fcb112064ef6774436d4f65acd5a1/pandas-0.20.3-cp27-cp27m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
```

But I get following error while building `docker-image` using same `dockerfile`:

```
---> Running in c8ddcdcdb155
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:02 --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to proxy.temp.com port 8080: No route to host
```

Same command runs and downloads package on bare metal node on which docker is installed. But while building docker-image it gives above error. What is the issue, how can I download this package required for my image?

Also tried setting environment variables in my dockerfile before downloading pandas package as below,

```
ENV http_proxy 'http://myid_9076:pwd123*@proxy.temp.com:8080/'
ENV https_proxy 'http://myid_9076:pwd123*@proxy.temp.com:8080/'
```

but same error is seen in this case too.

Comment: It not that your `proxy.temp.com` domain is some record in you local hosts file?

Comment: @ttomalak DNS is included in /etc/resolv.conf file on bare metal machine. But is there any need to include this file anywhere in dockerfile commands while building docker image?

Comment: I mean more like in `/etc/hosts` but if you use some custom dns server you probably should map your resolv.conf file. Docker will not autamtically use any of your custom hosts configuration so you should explicitly map this addresses

Comment: Enter into docker, and `ping stackoverflow.com` to confirm if it is really dns issue. `ping proxy.temp.com` to see if it really your custom dns issue.

Comment: @atline getting following error while `ping stackoverflow.com` :                                                         `From *.*.*.254 (*.*.*.254) icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable`                          Further link at https://superuser.com/questions/175428/how-to-ping-when-behind-a-proxy shows I cant ping behind proxy

Comment: So did you try `curl https://stackoverflow.com`? Anyway, I just want to confirm if you can access any outside network with domain name, and if you can access any direct ip address from the container to narrow down it is a dns issue or network issue?

Comment: @atline but i tried pinging proxy server `proxy.temp.com` which i was able to ping from host machine but from dockerfile it gives error `Destination Host Unreachable`. For `curl https://stackoverflow.com` it give same error as `No route to host`

Comment: Could you try add `{"dns":["10.192.130.201"]}` to `/etc/docker/daemon.json` and restart docker daemon? The ip is your dns ip.

Comment: @atline for multiple ip-addresses we have to add by comma separated list right? `{"dns":["ip1","ip2"]}`. With these settings it still gives same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was network conflict issue, my network was conflicting with docker network. So I have set parameter `"bip"` in `/etc/docker/daemon.json` as shown below

```
{
    "bip" : "12.12.0.1/24"
}
```

Got the answer from link [Unable to access local network IP from docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41168747/unable-to-access-local-network-ip-from-docker-container)