# How to connect to hdfs from the docker container?

Tags: python, docker, hadoop, hdfs

My goal is to read file from hdfs in airflow and do further manipulations.

After researching, I found that url I need to use is as follows:

`df = pd.read_parquet('http://localhost:9870/webhdfs/v1/hadoop_files/sample_2022_01.parquet?op=OPEN')`,

where localhost/172.20.80.1/computer-name.mshome.net can be interchangeably used,

9870 - namenode port,

hadoop_files/sample_2022_01.parquet - my folder and file created in the root.

I can access and read file locally in PyCharm, but I am unable to get the same result inside airflow in docker. I tried using local hdfs and hdfs hosted in docker and changing host to the host.docker.internal, but I am getting the same error.

Stack trace:

```
[2022-06-12, 17:52:45 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1889} ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 1350, in do_open
    encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1281, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1327, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1276, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1036, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 976, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 948, in connect
    (self.host,self.port), self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 728, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 716, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
OSError: [Errno 113] No route to host

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 207, in execute
    branch = super().execute(context)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 171, in execute
    return_value = self.execute_callable()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 189, in execute_callable
    return self.python_callable(*self.op_args, **self.op_kwargs)
  File "/opt/airflow/dags/includes/parquet_dag/main.py", line 15, in main
    df_parquet = read('hdfs://localhost:9000/hadoop_files/sample_2022_01.parquet')
  File "/opt/airflow/dags/includes/parquet_dag/utils.py", line 29, in read
    df = pd.read_parquet('http://172.20.80.1:9870/webhdfs/v1/hadoop_files/sample_2022_01.parquet?op=OPEN')
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parquet.py", line 500, in read_parquet
    **kwargs,
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parquet.py", line 236, in read
    mode="rb",
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parquet.py", line 102, in _get_path_or_handle
    path_or_handle, mode, is_text=False, storage_options=storage_options
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py", line 614, in get_handle
    storage_options=storage_options,
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py", line 312, in _get_filepath_or_buffer
    with urlopen(req_info) as req:
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py", line 212, in urlopen
    return urllib.request.urlopen(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 525, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 543, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 1378, in http_open
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 1352, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 113] No route to host>
```

With host.docker.internal:

```
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use any routable address inside airflow docker container.

if hadoop is inside docker container as well, check it ip address using `docker inspect CONTAINER` ([doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/inspect/)). if hadoop is on localhost you can set `network_mode: "host"` ([doc](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#network_mode))

also there is an important notice if you are on macos and have the docker desktop app which basically a virtual machine. so in this case you need some extra settings, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41168747/unable-to-access-local-network-ip-from-docker-container), for example.

Comment: I added network_mode: "host" and removed port bindings under airflow-webserver, and webserver is unhealthy now.

Comment: Also I created a common network for airflow and hdfs: "Subnet": "192.168.0.0/24", "Gateway": "192.168.0.1". docker inspect namenode shows this address: "IPAddress": "192.168.0.3". If I use network: "OSError: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable", when I use namenode: "OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address".

Comment: could you give further advice?

Comment: And it says 'ERROR: for airflow-scheduler  Container "e9020320d092" exited with code 1.' if add network_mode: "host" to all the airflow services

Answer (score 0):

> where localhost/172.20.80.1/computer-name.mshome.net can be interchangeably used,

They shouldn't be interchangeable inside Docker network.

From Airflow, you could use Docker service names, **not** IP addresses, and ensure the containers are in the same bridge network (**not** host mode, which only works on Linux). `host.docker.internal` isn't correct either since you're trying to reach another container, not your host

https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/

I'd also recommend using Airflow Spark operators to actually read Parquet from HDFS, using Spark, not Pandas or WebHDFS. You can convert Spark dataframes to Pandas, if needed

Comment: I used host.docker.internal with local hdfs. I also created a shared network for both apps:
c2c7fa435f0a   dockernet                bridge    local
and added in both docker-compose files:
networks:
      - dockernet

networks:
  dockernet:
    external: true

I have a container named "namenode" which I'd like to connect to, so I changed the url to:
http://namenode:9870/webhdfs/v1/hadoop_files/sample_2022_01.parquet?op=OPEN

though, I am getting the same error: "Cannot assign requested address".
Do I connect the right way and have to research why it is unsuccessful?

Comment: In other words, if I have all containers in one bridge network, I should be able connect by using http://container-name:9870..., which is equal to http://host.docker.internal:9870... with local hdfs, right? Although, I am getting "Cannot assign requested address" in both cases.

Comment: They are not the same, no. If they are in the same bridge, then there's no reason to use the host address. You said HDFS is in a container, not "local"

Comment: And why can't you just use Spark instead of WebHDFS?

Comment: I set up hdfs locally first, then I tried to run it in docker and see if it resolves the host problem. I am unfamiliar with Spark, but will look into that.

Comment: Unclear why exactly you need HDFS if parquet files can exist without it.

Comment: It is used as storage for a bunch of large parquet files

Comment: You didn't say you have a Hadoop cluster, so you're only running one datanode. Therefore, the files cannot be larger than your one host machine's hard-drive, so you don't need HDFS. Using WebHDFS or Pandas will not read the files in parallel data blocks, which is the main reason you'd use Hadoop at all

Comment: I have to use it anyway, my machine is only for developing purpose. I am trying to read a sample csv file:

sc = SparkSession.builder.appName('spark_app').getOrCreate()

csvDF = sc.read.csv("hdfs://host.docker.internal:9000/hadoop_files/example.csv") and getting the "RuntimeError: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number", outside of docker it works well :/

Also there is a problem with timestamp field: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Illegal Parquet type: INT64 (TIMESTAMP(NANOS,false))

Comment: If you're reading a CSV file, you shouldnt be getting Parquet errors. I suggest creating a new post for Spark-specific issues

Comment: since I encountered 2 more problems with spark, I am gonna return to my previous way of handling. So if I use hdfs set up locally and "host.docker.internal:9870...", everything should work? and If I get "Cannot assign requested address" error, then it has something to do with reaching hdfs?

Comment: @Val I did some testing yesterday and it won't work. The datanodes register themselves by host or IP, meaning your datanode will be probably just be `localhost:9864`, for example for purposes of reading/writing HDFS data. WebHDFS requires multiple requests and direct communication with the individual datanodes to retrieve blocks returned by the namenode. Therefore, any requests from a container will get redirected back through `localhost`, the container itself, and not your host machine. Therefore, you must run Namenode and Datanode inside of Docker

Comment: As for Spark, worked fine for me https://github.com/OneCricketeer/docker-stacks/blob/master/hadoop-spark/spark-notebooks/hdfs-reader.ipynb